# e4 - removing elements from the application model

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to modify an existing `e4 Application Model`. In my modification I want to remove some elements inside the Application Model. E.g. Parts, Menu and so on. I am having the unique UI-Element-Id. How can I best remove some elements from the Application Model with this information.

At this time, I am going to use the `MApplication` class, and look at every children and children of the children, if there are many matches with an UI-Element-Id. But this approach is nasty I think.

```
    public void modifyApplikationModel(String uiElementId) {
            if (uiElementId == null || uiElementId.trim().equals("")) {
                return;
            }       
            //application is injected
            List<MAddon> addons = application.getAddons();
            Iterator<MAddon> addonIterator = addons.iterator();
            while (addonIterator.hasNext()) {
                MAddon addon = addonIterator.next();
                if (uiElementId.equals(addon.getElementId())) {
                    addonIterator.remove();
                }
            }
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `EModelService` `findElement` or `findElements` methods to search for model elements.

`findElement` finds a single element with a given id:

```
MUIElement element = modelService.findElement("id", application);
```

There are several flavors of `findElements`, the simplest is:

```
List<MPart> parts = modelService.findElements(application, "id", MPart.class, Collections.emptyList());
```

in both case `application` can be the `MApplication` or any other element you want to start the search from.

Once you have found your element you can remove it from the parent:

```
MElementContainer<MUIElement> parent = element.getParent();

parent.getChildren().remove(element);
```

you may also need to call `element.setToBeRendered(false)`

Note for an `MPart` you can use `EPartService.hidePart`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but how can I remove a retrieved MUIElement from the application model?

Comment: Added removal to answer

Comment: I have taken your approach for a HandledMenuItem and a Perspective, but I see the elements in my UI, nothing happen at the screen?

Comment: I have only done this with MPart there may be other requirements for menu items. For perspectives `EModelService` has `removePerspectiveModel`. Normally you would use a 'Visible-When Expression' to hide menu items.

Comment: There seems to be no point in removing any `MMenuElement` from its parent's children, eclipse framework simply doesn't give a fuck. Use `element.setToBeRendered(false)`, like @greg-449 suggested, and set visible flag to false if you feel like it, but do not remove it from the children list!